# Array count inside Handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to get arraycount inside handler.and then call webservice according to Count,.But array count give me array.

```
__weak NewsViewController *self_ = self;
    [table addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[tableDataArray count]); // This Line give error Capturing self strongly in this block lead to retain cycle;
        [self_ callWebService];
    }];
```

Comment: try [self_.tableDataArray count];

Comment: tabledataArray is not object of Class

Comment: maybe the problem is that, that tabledataArray is not declared where you would like to call it?

Comment: I think the error is in your first line.

Answer (score 1):

Try create a weak pointer to `tableDataArray` also (like self)

```
__weak typeof(NSMutableArray*) _w_tableDataArray = tableDataArray;
__weak NewsViewController *self_ = self;
[table addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[_w_tableDataArray count]); // This Line give error Capturing self strongly in this block lead to retain cycle;
        [self_ callWebService];
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you're creating a weak self you're not actually referencing it in the block. When you call `[tableDataArray count];` It's the equivalent of calling `self.tableDataArray` in your case you should be calling `self_.tableDataArray;`.

For clarity an exemplary use of this is as follows:

```
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tableDataArray;
...
...

__block __weak NewsViewController *welf = self;
[table addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"%li", welf.tableDataArray.count);
    [welf callWebService];
}];
```

*Yes `welf` stands for weak self.*